# how can I modify the data in dataframe

Tags: apache-spark-sql

I want to modify the date eg:2018-02-02 00:00:00  to 20180202.What should I do.
I have used the to_date and regexp_replace function to modify the data, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

What type of data is 2018-02-02 00:00:00 string or timestamp? maybe you should cast to string before use to_date.